# Python: iterate through functions with different arguments

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have a class with three functions:

```
class MyClass:
    
    def f1(self, int_arg):
        return int_arg
    
    def f2(self, list_arg):
        return list_arg
    
    def f3(self, int_arg, list_arg):
        return int_arg + sum(list_arg)
```

The value of the arguments of these functions is fixed:

```
int_arg = 1
list_arg = [1,2]
```

Now, I want to iterate through the functions of my class and execute them, in the following way:

```
for f in ['f1', 'f2', 'f3']:
    out = getattr(MyClass(), f)(<arguments>)
```

Now, what is a smart way of dealing with the fact that different functions have different arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you want to know which parameters a function receives.
For that you may use `inspect.signature`:

```
from inspect import signature

def sub_dict(d, keys):
    return dict((k, d[k]) for k in keys)

int_arg = 1
list_arg = [1,2]

params = dict(int_arg=int_arg, list_arg=list_arg)

for f in ['f1', 'f2', 'f3']:
    func = getattr(MyClass(), f)
    out = func(**sub_dict(params, signature(func).parameters))
```