# how to use dictionaries to store multiple functions with different argument requirements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a dictionary that looks like this (for a fun project):

```
_cardLibrary = {
    
    
    1: {'name': 'Strike',
        'cost': 1,
        'type': 'attack',
        'rarity': 'common',
        'action': [deal_damage]
       },
    
    2: {'name': 'Defend',
        'cost': 1,
        'type': 'skill',
        'rarity': 'common',
        'action': [give_block]
       },
    
    3: {'name': 'Bash',
        'cost': 2,
        'type': 'attack',
        'rarity': 'common',
        'action': 
            [deal_damage,
             apply_status] 

       }

}
```

I'd like to build a function " use(i) " which takes the specific card and executes the code stored inside of 'action'. As you can see in the third element, 'action' should be able to contain multiple functions, each of them requiring specific arguments.

For instance, deal_damage requires 3 arguments. Apply status requires 4.

deal_damage(caster, target, basedamage)
apply_status(caster, target, status, intensity)

Is there any way to create a function that calls all the functions stored inside every specific card?

I would also need some way to be able to pass the actual arguments to every one of the functions... Some of the arguments could be constant values. Like, for this specific card, status is always 1 and intensity is 1. However, target and caster really need to be defined in the initial use(caster, target) function...

So far, I've tried to iterate over every single function, however, this leaves me with the problem of not being able to pass the concrete arguments to every function...

I also tried this link: [Python: iterate through functions with different arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64043601/python-iterate-through-functions-with-different-arguments)

but for some reason, iIcannot make the code work

If this doesn't work at all, I was considering the possibility of making every single card a function itself, however, this is problematic for other reasons... specifically regarding scalability.

Any ideas on how can I approach this?

thank you all

Comment: Where do you get these arguments from? I.e., if you only had _one_ function in the `actions` list, how would you call it? Do they all have the same variable arguments, with only the constant arguments changing between functions?

Comment: When turn starts, so to speak, you define the arguments yourself. So, if you'd want to deal damage to an enemy, you'd just execute deal_damage('self', 0, 10) to deal 10 damage to enemy number 0. When enemy attacks, their formulas would look like deal_damage(0,'self',10) instead. If that action was to apply a status, the arguments of status also need to be defined... Cards should try to group actions. So only by defining caster and target, the other arguments would already be defined by the card itself... did I answer your question?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, all functions have a `caster` and a `target` argument, but the other arguments are not same between functions? And these other arguments stay constant throughout the game?

Comment: No, they change. They are specific to every card. maybe i could store this defined arguments in the card itself. Like Bash should apply 2 intensity of status 1. every other card would be somewhat similar.

Comment: "So, if you'd want to deal damage to an enemy, you'd just execute deal_damage('self', 0, 10) to deal 10 damage to enemy number 0." No, that isn't the question. Suppose that the code selects the `'Strike'` card. **How will you know** the values that should be passed in order to call `deal_damage`? When you use a `'Bash'` card, I assume that the `caster` and `target` will be the same, and that these are chosen from outside, according to who played the card - right? But the damage that will be dealt to the target - where does that come from? What status will be applied, at what intensity?

Comment: Is that information, perhaps, intrinsic to **the card**? Or will it depend on some information that can be looked up from the caster and/or target? (In the latter case, *why are these separate parameters*, given that we have to pass the caster and target anyway?) Basically, the question is not well enough defined yet; you need to think more about *what needs to happen* when a card is played.

Comment: You are right Karl, i'm building the system kind of "on the fly". So far is working, but i'm still thinking on the overall playing loop. Rather than being a "card game", it should be an AI that chooses what's the best playable card at any time, given the probability of what can happen in the following turns. To fully answer your question. The specific arguments of the function deal damage are indeed intrinsic for every card. Strike, will always do 6 damage. Bash will always apply the same status to the target and deal 8 damage. etc. Same for the block cards

Comment: However, the same deal_damage() function, also behaves differently according to the target and the caster. For instance, if the caster has '+3 strenght', then the attack will deal basedmg + 3 to the target. If the target is currently affected by 'vulnerable', it will recieve 50% more damage, and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to pre-define some arguments to each function. Then, when you need to call the functions, you will only need to specify the `caster` and `target` arguments:

```
from functools import partial

def deal_damage(caster, target, basedamage):
    print(f"{caster} dealt {basedamage} damage to {target}")

def give_block(caster, target, defense):
    print(f"{caster} blocked {defense} damage from {target}")

def apply_status(caster, target, status, intensity):
    print(f"{caster} applied {intensity}x{status} to {target}")


_cardLibrary = {
    "strike": {'name': 'Strike',
        'cost': 1,
        'type': 'attack',
        'rarity': 'common',
        'actions': [partial(deal_damage, basedamage=10)]
       },
    
    "defend": {'name': 'Defend',
        'cost': 1,
        'type': 'skill',
        'rarity': 'common',
        'actions': [partial(give_block, defense=5)]
       },
    
    "bash": {'name': 'Bash',
        'cost': 2,
        'type': 'attack',
        'rarity': 'common',
        'actions': 
            [partial(deal_damage, basedamage=5),
             partial(apply_status, status='stun', intensity=5)] 

       }
}
```

Note that I changed the keys of the dictionary to strings, and the `'action'` key in each card to `'actions'` because there can be multiple actions per card.

Then, in your game loop, you can call these `partial` objects like a regular function:

```
while True:
    print(f"You have {len(_cardLibrary)} cards: ")
    print(", ".join(_cardLibrary))
    u_in = input("What would you like to do? (or quit) ").lower()
    if u_in == "quit":
        print("Goodbye")
        break
    
    try:
        card = _cardLibrary[u_in]
    except KeyError:
        print("Invalid choice. Please choose again")
        continue
    
    print(f"You played the {card['name']} card")
    for action in card['actions']:
        print("ACTION: ", end="")
        action(caster="You", target="Enemy")
```

This gives the following output:

```
You have 3 cards: 
strike, defend, bash

What would you like to do? (or quit) strike
You played the Strike card
ACTION: You dealt 10 damage to Enemy
You have 3 cards: 
strike, defend, bash

What would you like to do? (or quit) bash
You played the Bash card
ACTION: You dealt 5 damage to Enemy
ACTION: You applied 5xstun to Enemy
You have 3 cards: 
strike, defend, bash

What would you like to do? (or quit) defend
You played the Defend card
ACTION: You blocked 5 damage from Enemy
You have 3 cards: 
strike, defend, bash

What would you like to do? (or quit) quit
Goodbye
```

Comment: I'll be trying it right now. Thank you so much!! Also, how do you write code so fast!? You barely took 5 minutes to answer. Really, thanks!!!! :)

Comment: did just that. Thank you again mate.

Answer (score 0):

You could make all your function parameter lists end with `,**_` which will let them receive (and ignore) parameters they're not actually processing.  This will allow you to add fixed value parameters directly in the `_cardLibrary` dictionary and use it as parameters to the functions. Then define you `use()` function to add its own list of named arguments to the dictionary's fixed values as an override:

```
def deal_damage(caster,target,basedamage,**_):
    # ...


def use(card, **kwargs):
    for function in _cardLibrary[card]['action']:
        function(**{**_cardLibrary[card],**kwargs})
```

usage:

```
use(1,caster="orc",target="human") 

# assuming _cardLibrary supplies the default value for "baseDamage" on card #1
```

Comment: Man, I really feel so noob sometimes. I didn't even know you could do this. This is super useful.  Thank you so much!